# Django+redis error on request.user

Tags: django, redis

I configured Django to work with Redis. In principle everything went well.

The redis caches the user name, I log in with John, when I call the view that uses the cache comes with different user name.

In my template I get the username with {{request.user}}.
How do i proceeed?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, we need to see some code to be able to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

part of my views.py
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

```
@cache_page(86400)
def schedule_complete_list(request):
    equipments = Equipment.objects.all()
    ctx = {'equipments' : equipments, }
    return render (request, 'schedule.html', ctx )
```

Cache is generated when the page is accessed for the first time right?  At that time I was logged in as Admin, i logged out and logged in as Erico.   In my navbar where i have {{ request.user }}

The user name should be Ericoo, but Admin appears.
This is being filled with cache data, not {{request.user}}

Comment: But I'm not sure why this surprises you. You cached the entire page, including the part where it outputs the username.